# Spring, Thymeleaf and localized strings

Tags: spring-mvc, netbeans, thymeleaf

I am new to using Spring and Thymeleaf and I can't figure out where to put my localization .properties files. I have this Bean:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {

    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages/messages", "classpath:messages/validation");
    // if true, the key of the message will be displayed if the key is not
    // found, instead of throwing a NoSuchMessageException
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    // # -1 : never reload, 0 always reload
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);

    return messageSource;
}
```

Inside login.html:

```
    <p th:text="#{messages.hello}">Welcome to our site!</p>
```

Inside `messages_en.properties` :

```
    messages.hello=Apparently messages work
```

My project structure:

[image: structure]

I have tried creating a folder inside WEB-INF called messages but apparently I am not getting something right. Any ideas?

Edit: Updated question with code relevant to mesages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this one is old. But I have looked for a solution and got to this post.
I have found a solution by myself and others with the same problem might get here.

So this is how I solved it:

Inject `MessageSource` into `SpringTemplateEngineBean`.

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(MessageSource messageSource, ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver) { 
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    engine.setMessageSource(messageSource);
    return engine;
}
```

Now Thymeleaf knows about your `MessageSource` and evaluates your expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Sadly the project was terminated not long after I posted this question.

Comment: There is no need to set `messageSource`, Spring automatically integrate `MessageSource` with `SpringTemplateEngine` bean. Like below @user882209 answer.

Answer (score 3):

*Basename* in this XML means *prefix of* `.properties` *files that contain different translations*.

Let's say that you need two languages: English (`en`) and Polish (`pl`).
All you need to do is to set your `Basename` to `messages` like this:

```
messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
```

and then put two files `messages_en` and `messages_pl` in your `classpath` (`WEB-INF` should suffice, although consider using `src/main/resources` directory).

This is a basic example that should be easily adapted to your case.

Comment: I have done as you advised, placed a file named `messages_en.properties` in `src/main/resources` directory. Yet still the tag `<p th:text="#{message.hello}">Welcome to our site!</p>` displays as `??message.hello_en??`

I have the feeling that something really basic is escaping me..

Comment: I don't have experience with Thymeleaf, but without using it I've succesfully displayed localized messages with `<spring:message code="messages.hello" />` etc. Please include more code, this might help to tell if the error is on the backend or frontend.

Comment: Hmm that is weird.. I used `<spring:message code="messages.hello"/>` and nothing displayed on the browser. What I am trying to do, is work with [this Spring Web Guide](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-web/tree/master/6). I just put the localization files and `<p th:text="#{message.hello}">Welcome to our site!</p>` along with `<spring:message code="message.hello" />` in the `home.html` file.

Something else must be going on.. Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: This tag requires some additional configuration to work. Please include all your code relevant to messages in the question.

Comment: As I said before, I have no experience in Thymeleaf so I can't give you any more help. To set up localization in Spring you need to configure additional beans - for me [this article](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example/) was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. This guide is indeed helpfull but I think something else is the problem. I will continue my hunt and will let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: I'd suggest first getting it to work with the tutorial above (using spring:message tags) and then trying to change them for Thymeleaf's th:text

Comment: Yes, I eventually used the tutorial you provided (apparently it worked..) and switched to using apache tiles and jsp.
Maybe I will give Thymeleaf another try sometime in the future.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You should expose Thymeleaf's `SpringTemplateEngine` as bean to let Spring inject your `MessageSource` into it:

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}
```

For information about `MessageSource` configuration see **Michał Rybak**'s answer.